# ¿como validar que php este funcionando en debian 8?

Tags: php, linux, servidor, debian

Acabo de instalar debian en mi equipo para utilizarlo como servidor y he instalado php, mysql y phpmyadmin pero no se como validar que si los instale bien ya que la interfaz es por medio de comandos, así que quisiera saber que comandos puedo utilizar para validar que me hayan quedado bien instalados estos programas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para comprobar si php esta instalado puedes verificar la version del mismo, para esto puedes usar la terminal de linux con el comando:

```
php -v
```

Este retornará algo como:

```
PHP 5.6.26-0+deb8u1 (cli) (built: Sep 21 2016 12:37:50) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

Para comprobar que apache esta corriendo con los modulos necesarios, por ejemplo el modulo de php5, puedes usar el comando

```
apache2ctl -M
```

Este comando te retornará algo como:

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
```

Alternativamente a usar estos comandos puedes crear un archivo index.php en tu server (/var/www/html) y dentro de este colocar:

```
<?php
  echo phpinfo();
?>
```

Con eso compruebas la versión de PHP y todos los módulos disponibles para PHP en apache por ejemplo el modulo `php5-mysqlnd` que permite la conexión entre PHP y MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

En la consola ingresa el siguiente comando:

```
 php -v
```

debería de regresar el siguiente mensaje:

```
 Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
  Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
  with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
```

saludos.

Comment: Esto solo validaría que el CLI funciona, cabe la posibilidad que no esté correctamente configurado para funcionar con el servidor web.